# How to rewrite POST request body on HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, post, encryption

I'm working on a Filter in which I have to get the request payload, decrypt it, check if it's a valid JSON and if it is go on with the chain and go to my service. The thing is that, so far I haven't been able to find a way to rewrite the body. Why I want to rewrite it? As the service expects a JSON and the request has an encrypted text in the body, once I decrypt it I want the body to be the decrypted JSON. Also, once I return from the service, I should rewrite the response to have the json encrypted. I've read a lot of forums and questions but couldn't get to a working solution.

Here's my code:

**RequestLoginFilter.java**

```
    @WebFilter("/RequestLoginFilter")
public class RequestLoginFilter implements Filter{

    protected final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(RequestLoginFilter.class);

    private ServletContext context;

    private CryptoUtil crypto;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
        this.context.log("RequestLoggingFilter initialized");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
//       use wrapper to read multiple times the content
        AuthenticationRequestWrapper req = new AuthenticationRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request);
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String payload = req.getPayload();
        try {
            String decryptedPayload = crypto.decrypt(payload);
            JSONUtils.convertJSONStringToObject(decryptedPayload, LoginTokenTO.class);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            logger.error("Error when trying to decrypt payload '"+payload+"'");
            throw new ServletException("Error when trying to decrypt payload '"+payload+"'", e);
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        System.out.println("a ver");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And also the wrapper, just in case:

**AuthenticationRequestWrapper.java**

```
public class AuthenticationRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    protected final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AuthenticationRequestWrapper.class);

    private final String payload;

    public AuthenticationRequestWrapper (HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationException {
        super(request);

        // read the original payload into the payload variable
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            // read the payload into the StringBuilder
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                    stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } else {
                // make an empty string since there is no payload
                stringBuilder.append("");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.error("Error reading the request payload", ex);
            throw new AuthenticationException("Error reading the request payload", ex);
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException iox) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
        payload = stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream () throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes());
        ServletInputStream inputStream = new ServletInputStream() {
            public int read () 
                throws IOException {
                return byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }
        };
        return inputStream;
    }

    public String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

Hopefully somebody here knows how I can get to get this working.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst what you are asking is probably technically possible, it doesn't sound like the right approach to me.

What you need is a security layer that sits between the incoming request (endpoint) and your service.  Re-writing the body of the request is a strange thing to be doing (which probably explains why you're having issues).  Is there a reason you want this to be done in a `Filter`?  After all, `filters` are designed to filter requests, not rewrite them ;)

A more logical/transparent solution would be to have your endpoint accept all incoming requests, decrypt and validate them before passing the request onto your service tier.  Something like this:

```
public void handleRequest(Request request) {
    try {
        IncomingRequest x = securityManager.decrypt(request);
        Response r = myService.handleRequest(x);
        handleResponse(securityManager.encrypt(r));
    }catch(InvlidateMessage x) {
        handleInvalidMessage...
    }catch(BusinessException x) {
        handleBusinessException...
    }
}
```